# how to set the drag and zoom image center to the layout?

Tags: android, image, zooming, drag

In my application i want to drag the image and zoom the image.So that i followed the bellow link.

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/05/zoom-image-demo-in-android-zoom-image.html

By using this every thing is working good. But my requirement is when ever enter the activity the drag image is center to the layout. In this sample the image is fill parent in xml layout. And apply the scale type is matrix.So the image is by default top of the left corner.If the image is wrap content,the image is drag with in that area. But my requirement is the image is center to the layout and drag the image with in the full layout.For that I googled alot. So please guide me how to do this? This is the 
xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scaleType="matrix" 
android:src="@drawable/images" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the activity

```
*public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageDetail;
    LinearLayout linear;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint = new PointF();
    PointF midPoint = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageDetail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageDetail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

        ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE);
        imageDetail.setColorFilter(filter);


        /**
         * set on touch listner on image
         */
        imageDetail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());

                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        Log.e("action down","down");
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                        oldDist = spacing(event);

                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(midPoint, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                                    event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x,
                                        midPoint.y);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    }
                    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                    return true;

            }

            @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });

    }*
```

Comment: Can you post xml and some code?

Comment: same as the above link